# Orah, Or and Torah

Tags: commentaries, language, etymology

I found [this](http://www.aish.com/atr/What-is-Torah.html) on the Aish website:

> The accurate meaning of “Torah” is twofold. Firstly it comes from the word “**הוֹרָה**,” which means teaching. More precisely it means “teaching with direction,” i.e. the type of teaching which enables and empowers one with a direction to proceed. The same word could be used in Hebrew with such teachings both in spiritual and secular realms.
>
> The second meaning is from the word “**אורה**,” which means light. One
>   example of this reflected in the verse which states, “A mitzvah is a
>   candle, and Torah is the light” (Proverbs 6:23).

Would someone please help me out to see the connection? Both hebrew words hora'ah and orah come from different roots, that's why I don't understand the connection being made.

Comment: I think we’ve been through this before. תורה comes from הרה. I’m pretty sure that the תורה-אורה connection solely refers to the Proverbs verse comparing the two.

Comment: I agree with @DonielF . There is no connection. We can think of two separate ways of understanding the word Torah either coming from "teaching" or from "light".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok maybe that's exactly what I wanted to know; so it's either הרה or it's ירה

Comment: I'm not that sure OP is that far off. Why is the Aramaic word for Torah אוריתא which seems to come from or be related to אורה?

Comment: @DanF Thought of that also. I'm only asking these kind of questions because most people seem to base their teachings upon different roots from which they assume the word Torah is derived. I'm just trying to make sense of it and see were all these assumptions came from or are based upon. And secondly I'm trying to figure out if some of these roots which are used share a etymological connections or formrelations or not. Or if there's a connection because words are homophone or homohraph, homonym or connected in any other way.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok derived from the root ירה, the verb meaning to 'teach' is הורה. It's cognates include תורה and מורה ..The word הורה written with a kamats to form 'horah' can also be written with a segol to form horeh (parent). So it's possible to say that horeh is also a cognate? Or is it just another (similar) connection like the connection beween הורה and אורה?

Comment: @Levi I'm sorry I don't understand the difference between "cognate" and "connection". Oxford English Dictionary defines "cognate" (of a word) as 'having the same linguistic derivation as another (e.g. English father, German Vater, Latin pater)'.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok With cognate I meant: related by language, or of similar nature. But the main point was to show that although there might or might not be a relation, there is at least a similtude between these words.